# Display a list of child posts on parent posts of a custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, child-pages, hierarchical

I have a hierarchical custom post type called 'products'and I have created a 2 level parent-child relationship. I want to list all the subpages/child posts on each parent post but I have tried everything and nothing works.

I tried the page-list plugin and it only works for the default 'Page' post type.
Same with the tutorial found on wpbeinner.com titled "How to Display a List of Child Pages For a Parent Page in WordPress". Both work for default page type but not the custom post types.

Would appreciate some input.
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The best way is using WP_Query. I think your error or plugin error could be that the 'post_type' of childs is not define.

WP Query : https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

```
global $post;

$args = array(
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'products', //you can use also 'any'
    );

$the_query = new WP_Query( $args );
// The Loop
if ( $the_query->have_posts() ) :
while ( $the_query->have_posts() ) : $the_query->the_post();
  // Do Stuff
    the_title();
    echo "<br>";
    the_content();
endwhile;
endif;
// Reset Post Data
wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: maybe you can change staus as resolved :D

Comment: I'm not sure how to mark it as resolved but I just clicked the "Answer Approval" link which by the way needs a label or something. It was not easy to find. 

Thanks.

Comment: thanks for highlighting can use 'any' - this was the helpful part I needed